# how to get class pointer from mid function hook

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, directx-9

I created a sample midfunction hook. But struck at crashing when I dereference a pointer.
Let say I hook to the middle of 
public: `virtual long __stdcall CD3DBase:DrawIndexedPrimitive(enum _D3DPRIMITIVETYPE, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)`

which is located in d3d9.dll. Below is an start assembly code of `CD3DBase:DrawIndexedPrimitive`:

```
.text:10029760                 mov     edi, edi
.text:10029762                 push    ebp 
.text:10029763                 mov     ebp, esp 
.text:10029765                 push    0FFFFFFFFh 
.text:10029767                 push    offset loc_1014A0AC 
.text:1002976C                 mov     eax, large fs:0 
.text:10029772                 push    eax 
.text:10029773                 sub     esp, 28h 
.text:10029776                 push    ebx
```

The hook start at `.text:10029765 push 0FFFFFFFFh`
I just change it to jump to my function. The jump statement is only 5 byte as usual, `0xE9(JMP) [Offset]`
In my function I try to get class pointer because I want to use it to call other function in the calss. Below is my code to get it

```
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9  g_deviceInterface; 
__declspec(naked) void WINAPI MyDipFunc()  
{ 

    //Here I get this pointer. As I know the this pointer is in EBP + 0x08 
    __asm mov EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP + 0x08]  
    __asm mov  DWORD PTR DS:[g_deviceInterface], EAX  

    //Replace code.  
    __asm PUSH 0xFFFFFFFF  //2 
    __asm PUSH 0x67F3A0AC  //7 
    __asm MOV EAX,DWORD PTR FS:[0] //12 
    __asm PUSH EAX //13 
    __asm SUB ESP,0x28 //16 
}
```

The result is that `MyDipFunc` is hit when the original function is called but when I execute `g_deviceInterface->GetStreamSource(....)` it crash.

Note: I know that class pointer will be pass through the first argument of callee, `CD3DBase:DrawIndexedPrimitive`, which is `[EBP+8]`.

Can someone advice if it do something wrong?

Thanks,

**Edited:** For more clear on my problem

My assumption is that `g_deviceInterface` may not be set properly as the class pointer may not be in `[EBP+0x08]`. I don't how can I get the class pointer which should be store in some place on the stack which is managed by `CD3DBase:DrawIndexedPrimitive`'s caller.

**Edited2:** My full hook function

```
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9  g_deviceInterface = NULL; 
__declspec(naked) void WINAPI MyDipFunc()  
{ 

    //Here I get this pointer. As I know the this pointer is in EBP + 0x08 
    __asm mov EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP + 0x08]  
    __asm mov  DWORD PTR DS:[g_deviceInterface], EAX  

    //Replace code.  
    __asm PUSH 0xFFFFFFFF  //2 
    __asm PUSH 0x67F3A0AC  //7 
    __asm MOV EAX,DWORD PTR FS:[0] //12 
    __asm PUSH EAX //13 
    __asm SUB ESP,0x28 //16 

    if(g_deviceInterface != NULL)
    {
         LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 StreamData;
         UINT OffsetInBytes;
         UINT Stride;
         if(g_deviceInterface->GetStreamSource(0,&StreamData,&OffsetInBytes,&Stride) == D3D_OK) //Crash at this line
         {
              if(StreamData != NULL)
                   StreamData->Release();
         }
    }

    __asm jmp [DIPJmpBack] //Jump back to caller, DIPJmpBack contain address to jump
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the pointer is pointing at valid memory?

Comment: The code is a bit incomplete. It would also be nice to start with a small example. The `g_deviceInterface->GetStreamSource(....)` is not shown, and by itself I don't expect this C++ call to dereference a pointer by itself (unself GetStreamSource is a virtual method)

Comment: Is it possible that the interface pointer is no longer valid at the point where you try to call it? Have you tried calling AddRef on it from your hook?

Comment: The g_deviceInterface could not a valid pointer actually. But how can I get it from hooked function?

Comment: After the patched point, does the new target code do everything that was done by the jumped-around code, plus clean up before returning?  Maybe your code is working okay  but crashes when it tries to return.  (You don't say if you have single stepped through this code.)